# Use tableviewcell for create a. table of contents in swift

Tags: swift

I want create a table of contents and multiple page like a books
I create a tableview with 4 row for exemple module1 module2 module3 ....
 each module contains multi pages module1(page1,page2,....) My problem : 
how to pass to the pages of each module
 I create a collectionview to present all pages
how does these steps In swift
Tahnks

Comment: It is not clear what you want to implement. Do you have any data structure or code you can add?

Answer (score 0):

You can make nested table ,inside every cell put a table.
You should use two dimension array for implement it.